# CentOS6 - httpd - mod_file_cache

Tags: centos, httpd, centos6

It appears that CentOS 6 no longer supports a few apache modules (mod_file_cache, mod_mem_cache, and mod_imagemap) according to their [docs](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Migration_Planning_Guide/ch04s04.html).

What's the best way to handle this? Just remove the references from httpd.conf, or download and compile manually?

I Was thinking of just removing and seeing if my codebase worked as expected, then if something broke, compiling manually. Hoping that I can safely remove these modules from httpd.conf and everything still works.

Comment: Was this stock Apache that came with CentOS?

Comment: @Rilindo: Yes it was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up just removing the references from httpd.conf and everything seems to work so far.